# Can't click on certain taskbar icons in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, taskbar

I'm using Windows 10. Certain taskbar icons have stopped working: they're there, but if I click on them, nothing happens. These are: date and time; audio; wifi. Other taskbar icons are working fine if I click on them: Dropbox, antivirus etc.

Things I've tried:

- Restarting Windows Explorer
- Turning the PC off and on again
- Checking for updates

Can anyone help?

Comment: Try to test Windows integrity by running [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: @harrymc I've now done this, and SFC; no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to run as admin, command prompt and then `sfc /scannow`

Comment: I've now done this, and DISM; no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

As testing Windows integrity by running
[Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html)
and
[sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html)
did not help, a more consequent measure is called for.

I suggest doing a
[Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html)
with the latest Windows 10 release.
This is the same operation as doing a major Windows update, so take
the same precautions.